# Overwrite due to buffer overflow

Tags: c, buffer, overflow, overwrite

```
char A[3] = "AA";
char B[4];

printf("Type : ");
gets(B);

char AB[20];  // just big size
strncpy(AB, A, 3);
strncat(AB, B, 4);

printf("%s", AB);
```

Yes I know this is vulnerable code (b/c gets).

If I type "BBB" then char AB prints "AABBB".

If I type "BBBB" then char AB prints "BBBB"

I know char B overflows. But, when I concatenate A & B in bigger buffer, A gets disappear, why is it happening? Can someone explain clearly?

Comment: *Undefined behavior*. Practically though, it really depends on where the compiler puts the two arrays `A` and `B`, especially in relation to each other.

Comment: What @Someprogrammerdude said. Furthermore, `B` now (probably) extends down into `AB`'s memory  (because it overflowed), when appending `B` on `AB`, the processing of `B` will walk into the space occupied (possibly) by `AB`, so the `strncat()` is now concatenating itself onto itself.

Comment: If `B` immediately follows `A` in memory, then entering `BBBB` results in four `B` characters being stored in `A`, and the terminating null byte being stored in the first element of `B`.  So when accessed, `A` is a null-terminated `BBBB` and `B` is simply an empty string.  Their concatenation is just a null-terminated `BBBB`.  But this is all undefined behavior, and you cannot rely on any of this.  Even if you know memory is allocated this way, indexing past the end of an array violates assumptions the compiler may make about what could change, so optimization may cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

With an input of `"BBBB"`, which occupied 5 bytes in memory - four letters and the \0 terminal - the variable `B` extends up to `A`. Then the \0 terminal of `B` becomes the first byte of `A`, and then `A` is now an empty string. Son when you concat `B` to `A` in `AB`, the result is `B`.